# How to stop unauthorized automatic transmissions?

Tags: networking

My GNU/Linux system transmits data over the Internet whether I ask it to or not. How can I make it stop?

For example, without asking, my system's Firefox software evidently contacts Mozilla.org in the background. Likewise, without asking, my system's GNOME software solicits notifications over the network from somebody. (These are just examples. I am not asking how to configure Firefox or GNOME specifically. Rather, I am asking how to stop unauthorized automatic transmissions generally.)

I want my system

- to connect to the Internet but
- to remain silent until **I ask** the system to transmit data and
- to transmit data, when I ask, only to my intended recipient.

How can I make my system stop babbling?

(For information, my distribution is Debian. However, Debian, Fedora and Arch users are equally welcome to answer.)

Comment: Generally your options are to either configure the software or set up very restrictive firewall rules. If you're worried about privacy then really you should strip down your system to less components in which you understand well and can configure/secure.

Comment: @Torin As I feared. Unfortunate. With a GNOME desktop, my Debian box has 2500 packages installed. To inspect all of them against unauthorized automatic transmissions does not seem very realistic.

Comment: @Torin I had thought of configuring a firewall but there isn't a dedicated network port for unauthorized automatic transmissions. It's not like I could solve the problem by blocking port 9999 (or whatever number), is it?

Comment: Firewall rules can filter on other criterion such as destination port, but it's likely to not be very useful as most traffic will likely be HTTPS. Usually software making connection is for statistics/updates and can be disabled in any reputable software. Otherwise if you don't trust the software, then running it can't be considered safe.

Comment: Firefox tells you all about it, in a pretty visible place, when you run it the first time. And it's not secret how to stop those connections. Just follow the prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an [application firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_firewall). One in progress is [OpenSnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch), modeled after Little Snitch for macOS. It works but comes with disclaimers not to bank on it yet. Better might be the far more mature and widespread AppArmor, an [LSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules) providing more than just control over network access; it also implements [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) and other features. (Thus, do not use AppArmor and SELinux simultaneously.) Debian 10 (Buster), 6 July 2019, has AppArmor enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

- You can `unshare' the network for a process and they will only see the loopback. That might work for some software or if you are running really untrusted software. It's a bit overkill though, the process will only see something similar to a private, no shareable, loopback.
- You can "silence" Firefox a lot. [This](https://github.com/ghacksuserjs/ghacks-user.js) is a nice starting point. Note that things like predictive loading or an adblocker checking its list of sites will eventually create traffic, and the browser is not always to blame. Also any page doing XHR will create traffic when you think nothing at all should be happening.
- proxy everything, with SOCKS for example, then you can decide who goes through. SOCKS5 doing DNS means that you can kill the local network DNS too, that should keep most things under control. Wrapping the programs you trust with torify/tsocks does the rest.
- there is something that solves two things at once: Tor Browser (it's basically Firefox) offers a local SOCKS5 proxy by default, so if you proxy everything, most traffic will go trough only if you have the Tor browser open. You could even point a normal Firefox (with containers and whatever you don't get with Tor) to it. Then you "hold the key"; if Tor browser is not open, nobody gets to use the internet (except for DNS-less based traffic that you would have to block with iptables or something like that).